# What does it mean to say that the space of convex bodies is locally compact with respect to the Hausdorff metric?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, visualization, convex-geometry, hausdorff-distance

I know that this is equivalent to requiring each convex body in the space having a compact neighborhood. Still I can't visualize this.